# HTML Hotkey Input Control

Tags: html, input, widget

Is there an HTML widget that mimics the hotkey input control that is natively available in Windows such has [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/hot-key-controls)?

Essentially I want to provide an input field to the user where they can press the desired hotkey combination which I can then store in my app settings.

Edit: Forgot to add - the app is written using Electron.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm making an electron application as well and was looking if anyone tackled this problem already. Apparently not. Here's what I ended up using in plain typescript:

```
let hotkeyInput = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("hotkey-input");
let modifiers = [
    "ShiftLeft",
    "ShiftRight",
    "ControlLeft",
    "ControlRight",
    "AltLeft",
    "AltRight",
    "AltLeft",
    "OSLeft",
    "MetaLeft",
    "MetaRight",
    "OSLeft",
    "OSRight",
];
hotkeyInput.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    let key = event.code;
    if (key !== "Tab") {    // Allow tabbing through inputs
        event.preventDefault();    // Prevent generation of input events
        let hotkey = "";
        if (key === "Backspace") this.value = "";
        hotkey += event.shiftKey ? "Shift + " : "";
        hotkey += event.ctrlKey ? "Ctrl + " : "";
        hotkey += event.altKey ? "Alt + " : "";
        hotkey += event.metaKey ? "Meta + " : "";
        if (key.startsWith("Key")) key = key.slice(3);
        if (!modifiers.includes(key)) hotkey += key;
        // We only want key combinations
        if (event.shiftKey || event.ctrlKey || event.altKey || event.metaKey) this.value = hotkey;
    }
});
```

Note, this assumes that `hotkeyInput` is plain `<input id="hotkey-input" type="text">`.